# Can I make tsc "constant-fold" when type-checking indexer signatures?

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code, compiled with `--noImplicitAny`:

```
interface T {
    ax: any,
    bx: any,
}

const prefixes: ("a" | "b")[] = ["a", "b"];
const keys: ("ax" | "bx")[] = ["ax", "bx"];
const t: T = { ax: "foo", bx: "bar" };

for (const key of keys) {
    const value = t[key]; // <- works
}

for (const prefix of prefixes) {
    const value = t[prefix + "x"]; // <- TS7017 error
}
```

By inspection, we can see that the statements in both the for-of loops should work. In the first loop, the type of `key` exactly matches the implicit type of the indexer on `T`. In the second loop, the type of `prefix + "x"` should by all rights be `("ax" | "bx")`, which is again the type of the indexer in question.

However, tsc raises a TS7017 error on the second loop ("Element implicitly has 'any' type because type 'T' has no index signature.").

Is there anything I can do to get this to type-check while still maintaining type-safety (so, *not* by just putting an explicit `(t as any)` to silence the warning)? If not, is there a Github issue or something tracking this?

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately TypeScript does not compute literal types from operations on other literal types.

You need to use a type assertion.

```
const value = t[<keyof T>(prefix + "x")];
```

In more detail, if the type of an expression is `"a"` and the type of another expression is `"b"`, and say we store them in variables `x` and `y` respectively, the type of the expression `x + y` will *not* be `"ab"`.

It would be extremely nice if this *did* work and there are a number of open issues on GitHub which suggest that this or similar functionality be added. One even suggests the addition of regular expression literal types, which might be a little extreme but combining literal types would be extremely valuable for scenarios such as link generation and using the HTTP PATCH method in, for example, a strongly typed wrapper function internally delegating to `fetch`.